# Why does DBD::SQLite have a different query plan for an SQL statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, perl, dbi, sql-execution-plan

I have an `INSERT INTO... SELECT ... FROM` SQL statement that runs acceptably fast when executed from `SQLite's` command line shell.

However, if I execute the same statement (copy/pasted) with Perl's `DBI::SQLite`, the statement becomes slow.

The reason must be the execution plan: when I let the statement be explained from the shell and from within `DBI::SQLite`, they're different: the fast version uses the optimal indexes and table order, the slow version chooses to access the tables in a less than optimal way.

So, I have two questions.

1. Why is the plan different?
2. How can I make the plan used in the Perl environment the same as in
   the shell?

Comment: Have you looked at the output of statistics_info ? Does it show the indexes?

Comment: Do you use transactions in `DBI::SQLite` case (and commit infrequently)?  Any difference in settings when you connect from the script?  (Are REGEXP involved by any chance?)

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT sqlite_version();` in both cases?